# java stream convert list of POJO to Map of Map<String, List<POJO>>

Tags: java, java-stream

i have List of Foo class:

```
public class Foo {
  private Key key;
  private String value;
}
public class Foo.Key {
  private String category;
  private String pref;
  private String platform;
}
```

need to convert it to Map<String, Map<String, List> where first String is the Foo.Key.category, second String is Foo,Key.pref and Lookup class:

```
public class Lookup {
  private String platform;
  private String value;
}
```

currently i have this code:

```
Map<String,Map<String, List<Lookup>> map = Maps.newHashMap();
fooList.forEach(
        f -> {
          String category = f.getKey().getCategory();
          String pref = f.getKey().getPref();
          String platform = f.getKey().getPlatform();
          String value = f.getValue();

          Lookup data =
              Lookup.builder()
                  .platform(platform)
                  .value(value)
                  .build();

          if (map.get(category) == null) {
            map.put(category, new HashMap<>());
          }
          map.get(category).computeIfAbsent(pref, (x -> new ArrayList<>())).add(data);
        });
```

i tried to use Java stream but it won't compile:

```
fooList.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(f -> f.getKey().getCategory(), 
            Collectors.groupingBy(f -> f.getKey().getPref(), 
                Collectors.toList(f -> Lookup.Builder.platform(platform).value(value).build()))));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on streams:

```java
Map<String, Map<String, List<Lookup>>> converted = foos.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(foo -> foo.getKey().getCategory(),
        Collectors.groupingBy(foo -> foo.getKey().getPref(),
            Collectors.mapping(foo -> Lookup.builder().platform(foo.getKey().getPlatform()).value(foo.getValue()).build(),
                Collectors.toList()
            )
        )
    ));
```

As you can see, `Collectors.mapping` is the clue here.